# Drawing Arrows in p5js

Tags: javascript, graph-theory, p5.js

I happen to be working in a graph theory visualization project for college. For this project, we can't use any existing library that handles the graph storage and algorithms(so I can't use things like D3 or python's NetworkX). This project is more about the visualization of the algorithms(BFS, DFS, Dijkstra, Colouring, etc.), so I went for JavaScript using p5js as my visualization aid.

The problem I'm facing is that I'm trying to draw the arrows between the vertices, and it is not turning out as expected:

[image: the actual result]

**EDIT 1**

*changed the question to be in accord with the mod's comment.*

This is a `sketch.js` showing how I'm trying to make it work:

```
var x1; //starting vertex
var x2; //ending vertex
var r = 16; //vertex radius


function setup() {
    createCanvas(640, 480);
    x1 = createVector(random(0, width/2), random(0, height/2)); //random position to the upper left
    x2 = createVector(random(width/2, width), random(height/2, height)); //random position to the lower right
}

function draw() {
    background(200);
    stroke(0);
    var offset = r;
    ellipse(x1.x, x1.y, r, r); //starting vertex
    ellipse(x2.x, x2.y, r, r); //ending vertex
    line(x1.x, x1.y, x2.x, x2.y); //draw a line beetween the vertices

    // this code is to make the arrow point
    push() //start new drawing state
    var angle = atan2(x1.y - x2.y, x1.x - x2.x); //gets the angle of the line
    translate(x2.x, x2.y); //translates to the destination vertex
    rotate(angle); //rotates the arrow point
    triangle(-offset*0.5, offset, offset*0.5, offset, 0, -offset/2); //draws the arrow point as a triangle
    pop();
}
```

Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: You need to isolate your problem. Please post a [mcve] that shows just the code for drawing a single arrow from one hard-coded point to another hard-coded point. Your question has nothing to do with the actual graph code, so all of that code just makes it harder to answer your question.

Comment: Edited post to follow the MCVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With rotation set to 0 your arrow is pointing up when for 0 rotation it should be pointing to the right. One option is to draw the arrow so the tip is pointing east by default, otherwise you can simply offset the angle by -90 degrees (`-HALF_PI` radians):

```
// this code is to make the arrow point
    push() //start new drawing state
    var angle = atan2(x1.y - x2.y, x1.x - x2.x); //gets the angle of the line
    translate(x2.x, x2.y); //translates to the destination vertex
    rotate(angle-HALF_PI); //rotates the arrow point
    triangle(-offset*0.5, offset, offset*0.5, offset, 0, -offset/2); //draws the arrow point as a triangle
    pop();
```

check it out:

```js
var x1; //starting vertex
var x2; //ending vertex
var r = 16; //vertex radius


function setup() {
    createCanvas(640, 480);
    x1 = createVector(random(0, width/2), random(0, height/2)); //random position to the upper left
    x2 = createVector(random(width/2, width), random(height/2, height)); //random position to the lower right
}

function draw() {
    background(200);
    stroke(0);
    var offset = r;
    ellipse(x1.x, x1.y, r, r); //starting vertex
    ellipse(x2.x, x2.y, r, r); //ending vertex
    line(x1.x, x1.y, x2.x, x2.y); //draw a line beetween the vertices

    // this code is to make the arrow point
    push() //start new drawing state
    var angle = atan2(x1.y - x2.y, x1.x - x2.x); //gets the angle of the line
    translate(x2.x, x2.y); //translates to the destination vertex
    rotate(angle-HALF_PI); //rotates the arrow point
    triangle(-offset*0.5, offset, offset*0.5, offset, 0, -offset/2); //draws the arrow point as a triangle
    pop();
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, how could I imagine it was so simple. Thanks a lot. Marking as solved.

Comment: Quick question: right now the arrow point is exactly above the vertex, where should I use the offset, so it is just touching the vertex?

Comment: "just the tip ?" :P 
it's easy peasy: the tip of the arrow is the last pair of coordinates in the `triangle` call: simply remove the offset on the y axis: 0,0. (e.g. `triangle(-offset*0.5, offset, offset*0.5, offset, 0, 0);`

Comment: Thanks again, I"m feeling a little bit stupid for not seeing that. Then again, errors like these make you learn something for real :D Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9):

Arrow function:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth,windowHeight);
  cursor(ARROW);
  colorMode(HSL, 100);
}

function arrow(x,y,x2,y2,length,xs, ys, rotat, style, plan, xshadow, yshadow,txt){
  if (x == undefined) {
    x = 0;
  }
 if (y == undefined) {
    y = 0;
  }
  if (x == undefined) {
    x2 = 0;
  }
 if (y == undefined) {
    y2 = 0;
  }
  if (ys == undefined) {
    ys = 3;
  } else if (ys == '0') {
    ys = 0.0001;
  }
  if (xs == undefined) {
    xs = 5;
  } else if (xs == '0') {
    xs = 0.0001;
  }
  if (length == undefined) {
    length = 5;
  }
 var angle = atan2(y2-y, x2-x);
  if (rotat != undefined) { // write undefined without '' in the call to skip the rotating mode
    ys = ys*sin(frameCount/10);
  }
  var rxs = constrain(xs,0.0001,9);
  push();
  translate(x,y);
  rotate(angle);
  strokeJoin(ROUND);
  beginShape()
  if (plan == undefined || plan == '2D' || plan == '2d' || plan == '') {
  if (style == 'large') {
  vertex(0,-ys/1.5*length);
  } else if (style == 'pointy') {
  vertex(0,0);
  } else if (style == 'indication') {
  vertex(0,-ys*length);
  } else {
  vertex(0,-ys/3*length);
  }
  if (style == 'indication') {
  vertex(rxs*length, -ys*length);
  } else {
  vertex(rxs*length, -ys/3*length);
  }
  vertex(rxs*length, -ys*length);
  vertex(9*length, 0);
  vertex(rxs*length, ys*length);
  if (style == 'indication') {
  vertex(rxs*length, ys*length);
  } else {
  vertex(rxs*length, ys/3*length);
  }
  if (style == 'large') {
  vertex(0,ys/1.5*length);
  } else if (style == 'pointy') {
  vertex(0,0);
  } else if (style == 'indication') {
  vertex(0,ys*length);
  } else {
  vertex(0,ys/3*length);
  }
  } else if (plan == '3D' || plan == '3d') {
 var nl = false;
 if (length < 0) {
 length = abs(length);
 rotate(radians(180))
 nl = true;
 }
  var shadowx = 0;
  var shadowy = 0;
  if (xshadow != 0 || xshadow != undefined) {
  shadowx = length*xshadow;
  }
 if (xshadow == 0 || xshadow == undefined) {
  shadowx = 0.0001
  }
  if (yshadow != 0 || yshadow != undefined) {
  shadowy = length*yshadow;
  }
 if (yshadow == 0 || yshadow == undefined) {
  shadowy = 0.0001
  }
 if (nl == true) {
  shadowx = -shadowx
  shadowy = -shadowy
 }
  var yp = 0;
  if (style == 'large') {
  yp = ys/1.5*length;
  } else if (style == 'pointy') {
  yp = 0;
  } else if (style == 'indication') {
  yp = ys*length;
  } else {
  yp = ys/3*length;
  }
  var yq = 0;
  if (style == 'indication') {
  yq = ys*length;
  } else {
  yq = ys/3*length;
  }
  if (rotat != undefined) { // write undefined without '' in the call to skip the rotating mode
    shadowy = (abs(shadowy)+abs(shadowx))*sin(7.854+frameCount/10);
    shadowx = 0.01
    if (ys > 0) {
  vertex(0,-yp);
  vertex(rxs*length, -yq);
  vertex(rxs*length, -ys*length);
  vertex(9*length, 0);
  vertex(rxs*length, ys*length);
  vertex(rxs*length, yq);
  vertex(0,yp);
    } else {
  vertex(0+shadowx,-yp+shadowy);
  vertex(rxs*length+shadowx, -yq+shadowy);
  vertex(rxs*length+shadowx, -ys*length+shadowy);
  vertex(9*length+shadowx, 0+shadowy);
  vertex(rxs*length+shadowx, ys*length+shadowy);
  vertex(rxs*length+shadowx, yq+shadowy);
  vertex(0+shadowx,yp+shadowy);
    }
  }
 translate(-shadowx/2 ,-shadowy/2)
  if (rotat == undefined) {
  if (ys < 0) {
  if (shadowx > 0 && shadowy > 0){
  quad(0,-yp,rxs*length,-yq,shadowx+rxs*length,-yq+shadowy,shadowx,-yp+shadowy)
  quad(9*length,0,9*length+shadowx,0+shadowy,rxs*length+shadowx, ys*length+shadowy,rxs*length, ys*length)
  quad(9*length,0,9*length+shadowx,0+shadowy,rxs*length+shadowx, -ys*length+shadowy,rxs*length, -ys*length)
  } else if (shadowx < 0 && shadowy > 0){
  quad(9*length,0,9*length+shadowx,0+shadowy,rxs*length+shadowx, -ys*length+shadowy,rxs*length, -ys*length)
  quad(rxs*length+shadowx,-yq+shadowy,rxs*length, -yq,rxs*length, -ys*length,shadowx+rxs*length,-ys*length+shadowy)
  quad(rxs*length+shadowx,yq+shadowy,rxs*length, yq,rxs*length, ys*length,shadowx+rxs*length,ys*length+shadowy)
  quad(0,-yp,rxs*length,-yq,shadowx+rxs*length,-yq+shadowy,shadowx,-yp+shadowy)
  quad(shadowx,-yp+shadowy,0,-yp,0,yp,shadowx,yp+shadowy)
  } else if (shadowx < 0 && shadowy < 0){
  quad(9*length,0,9*length+shadowx,0+shadowy,rxs*length+shadowx, ys*length+shadowy,rxs*length, ys*length)
  quad(rxs*length+shadowx,-yq+shadowy,rxs*length, -yq,rxs*length, -ys*length,shadowx+rxs*length,-ys*length+shadowy)
  quad(rxs*length+shadowx,yq+shadowy,rxs*length, yq,rxs*length, ys*length,shadowx+rxs*length,ys*length+shadowy)
  quad(0,-yp,rxs*length,-yq,shadowx+rxs*length,-yq+shadowy,shadowx,-yp+shadowy)
  quad(0,yp,rxs*length,yq,shadowx+rxs*length,yq+shadowy,shadowx,yp+shadowy)
  quad(shadowx,-yp+shadowy,0,-yp,0,yp,shadowx,yp+shadowy)
  } else if (shadowx > 0 && shadowy < 0){
  quad(0,yp,rxs*length,yq,shadowx+rxs*length,yq+shadowy,shadowx,yp+shadowy)
  quad(9*length,0,9*length+shadowx,0+shadowy,rxs*length+shadowx, -ys*length+shadowy,rxs*length, -ys*length)
  quad(9*length,0,9*length+shadowx,0+shadowy,rxs*length+shadowx, ys*length+shadowy,rxs*length, ys*length)
  }
  } else if (ys > 0) {
  if (shadowx > 0 && shadowy > 0){
  quad(0,-yp,rxs*length,-yq,shadowx+rxs*length,-yq+shadowy,shadowx,-yp+shadowy)
  quad(0,yp,rxs*length,yq,shadowx+rxs*length,yq+shadowy,shadowx,yp+shadowy)
  quad(9*length,0,9*length+shadowx,0+shadowy,rxs*length+shadowx, -ys*length+shadowy,rxs*length, -ys*length)
  quad(9*length,0,9*length+shadowx,0+shadowy,rxs*length+shadowx, ys*length+shadowy,rxs*length, ys*length)
  } else if (shadowx < 0 && shadowy > 0){
  quad(9*length,0,9*length+shadowx,0+shadowy,rxs*length+shadowx, ys*length+shadowy,rxs*length, ys*length)
  quad(rxs*length+shadowx,-yq+shadowy,rxs*length, -yq,rxs*length, -ys*length,shadowx+rxs*length,-ys*length+shadowy)
  quad(rxs*length+shadowx,yq+shadowy,rxs*length, yq,rxs*length, ys*length,shadowx+rxs*length,ys*length+shadowy)
  quad(0,-yp,rxs*length,-yq,shadowx+rxs*length,-yq+shadowy,shadowx,-yp+shadowy)
  quad(0,yp,rxs*length,yq,shadowx+rxs*length,yq+shadowy,shadowx,yp+shadowy)
  quad(shadowx,-yp+shadowy,0,-yp,0,yp,shadowx,yp+shadowy)
  } else if (shadowx < 0 && shadowy < 0){
  quad(9*length,0,9*length+shadowx,0+shadowy,rxs*length+shadowx, -ys*length+shadowy,rxs*length, -ys*length)
  quad(rxs*length+shadowx,-yq+shadowy,rxs*length, -yq,rxs*length, -ys*length,shadowx+rxs*length,-ys*length+shadowy)
  quad(rxs*length+shadowx,yq+shadowy,rxs*length, yq,rxs*length, ys*length,shadowx+rxs*length,ys*length+shadowy)
  quad(0,yp,rxs*length,yq,shadowx+rxs*length,yq+shadowy,shadowx,yp+shadowy)
  quad(0,-yp,rxs*length,-yq,shadowx+rxs*length,-yq+shadowy,shadowx,-yp+shadowy)
  quad(shadowx,-yp+shadowy,0,-yp,0,yp,shadowx,yp+shadowy)
  } else if (shadowx > 0 && shadowy < 0){
  quad(0,yp,rxs*length,yq,shadowx+rxs*length,yq+shadowy,shadowx,yp+shadowy)
  quad(0,-yp,rxs*length,-yq,shadowx+rxs*length,-yq+shadowy,shadowx,-yp+shadowy)
  quad(9*length,0,9*length+shadowx,0+shadowy,rxs*length+shadowx, ys*length+shadowy,rxs*length, ys*length)
  quad(9*length,0,9*length+shadowx,0+shadowy,rxs*length+shadowx, -ys*length+shadowy,rxs*length, -ys*length)
  }
  }
  vertex(0,-yp);
  vertex(rxs*length, -yq);
  vertex(rxs*length, -ys*length);
  vertex(9*length, 0);
  vertex(rxs*length, ys*length);
  vertex(rxs*length, yq);
  vertex(0,yp);
  } else {
  if (shadowx > 0 && shadowy > 0){
  quad(0,-yp,rxs*length,-yq,shadowx+rxs*length,-yq+shadowy,shadowx,-yp+shadowy)
  quad(0,yp,rxs*length,yq,shadowx+rxs*length,yq+shadowy,shadowx,yp+shadowy)
  quad(9*length,0,9*length+shadowx,0+shadowy,rxs*length+shadowx, -ys*length+shadowy,rxs*length, -ys*length)
  quad(9*length,0,9*length+shadowx,0+shadowy,rxs*length+shadowx, ys*length+shadowy,rxs*length, ys*length)
  } else if (shadowx < 0 && shadowy > 0){
  quad(9*length,0,9*length+shadowx,0+shadowy,rxs*length+shadowx, ys*length+shadowy,rxs*length, ys*length)
  quad(rxs*length+shadowx,-yq+shadowy,rxs*length, -yq,rxs*length, -ys*length,shadowx+rxs*length,-ys*length+shadowy)
  quad(rxs*length+shadowx,yq+shadowy,rxs*length, yq,rxs*length, ys*length,shadowx+rxs*length,ys*length+shadowy)
  quad(0,-yp,rxs*length,-yq,shadowx+rxs*length,-yq+shadowy,shadowx,-yp+shadowy)
  quad(0,yp,rxs*length,yq,shadowx+rxs*length,yq+shadowy,shadowx,yp+shadowy)
  quad(shadowx,-yp+shadowy,0,-yp,0,yp,shadowx,yp+shadowy)
  } else if (shadowx < 0 && shadowy < 0){
  quad(9*length,0,9*length+shadowx,0+shadowy,rxs*length+shadowx, -ys*length+shadowy,rxs*length, -ys*length)
  quad(rxs*length+shadowx,-yq+shadowy,rxs*length, -yq,rxs*length, -ys*length,shadowx+rxs*length,-ys*length+shadowy)
  quad(rxs*length+shadowx,yq+shadowy,rxs*length, yq,rxs*length, ys*length,shadowx+rxs*length,ys*length+shadowy)
  quad(0,yp,rxs*length,yq,shadowx+rxs*length,yq+shadowy,shadowx,yp+shadowy)
  quad(0,-yp,rxs*length,-yq,shadowx+rxs*length,-yq+shadowy,shadowx,-yp+shadowy)
  quad(shadowx,-yp+shadowy,0,-yp,0,yp,shadowx,yp+shadowy)
  } else if (shadowx > 0 && shadowy < 0){
  quad(0,yp,rxs*length,yq,shadowx+rxs*length,yq+shadowy,shadowx,yp+shadowy)
  quad(0,-yp,rxs*length,-yq,shadowx+rxs*length,-yq+shadowy,shadowx,-yp+shadowy)
  quad(9*length,0,9*length+shadowx,0+shadowy,rxs*length+shadowx, ys*length+shadowy,rxs*length, ys*length)
  quad(9*length,0,9*length+shadowx,0+shadowy,rxs*length+shadowx, -ys*length+shadowy,rxs*length, -ys*length)
  }
  }
  }
  endShape(CLOSE);
 fill(0)
 if (plan == undefined || plan == '2D' || plan == '2d' || plan == ''){
 if (txt != undefined && style != 'pointy') {
    textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  textSize(constrain(Math.min((abs(length)*100)/textWidth(txt)*0.95,abs(ys*abs(length)/1.5)),0.000001,Infinity))
  text(txt,4.5*length,0);
 }
 if (txt != undefined && style == 'pointy') {
    textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  textSize(constrain(Math.min(abs(length)*75/textWidth(txt)*(Math.min(abs(9*length)-rxs*abs(length)+0.01,constrain(rxs*abs(length),(6*abs(length))-rxs*abs(length)+0.01,rxs*abs(length)))*0.5/(abs(length)*2))*0.95,abs(ys*abs(length)/1.5)*0.80),0.000001,Infinity))
  text(txt,4.5*length,0);
 }
 } else if (plan == '3D' || plan == '3d') {
 if (rotat != undefined) {
 if (ys > 0) {
 if (nl == true) {
 translate(4.5*length,0)
 rotate(radians(180))
 translate(-4.5*length,-0)
 }
 if (txt != undefined && style != 'pointy') {
    textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  textSize(constrain(Math.min((abs(length)*100)/textWidth(txt)*0.95,abs(ys*abs(length)/1.5)),0.000001,Infinity))
  text(txt,4.5*length,0);
 }
 if (txt != undefined && style == 'pointy') {
    textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  textSize(constrain(Math.min(abs(length)*75/textWidth(txt)*(Math.min(abs(9*length)-rxs*abs(length)+0.01,constrain(rxs*abs(length),(6*abs(length))-rxs*abs(length)+0.01,rxs*abs(length)))*0.5/(abs(length)*2))*0.95,abs(ys*abs(length)/1.5)*0.80),0.000001,Infinity))
  text(txt,4.5*length,0);
 }
 } else {
 if (nl == true) {
 translate(4.5*length,(-yq+shadowy+yq+shadowy)/2)
 rotate(radians(180))
 translate(-4.5*length,-(-yq+shadowy+yq+shadowy)/2)
 }
 if (txt != undefined && style != 'pointy') {
    textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  textSize(constrain(Math.min((abs(length)*100)/textWidth(txt)*0.95,abs(ys*abs(length)/1.5)),0.000001,Infinity))
  text(txt,4.5*length,(-yq+shadowy+yq+shadowy)/2);
 }
 if (txt != undefined && style == 'pointy') {
    textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  textSize(constrain(Math.min(abs(length)*75/textWidth(txt)*(Math.min(abs(9*length)-rxs*abs(length)+0.01,constrain(rxs*abs(length),(6*abs(length))-rxs*abs(length)+0.01,rxs*abs(length)))*0.5/(abs(length)*2))*0.95,abs(ys*abs(length)/1.5)*0.80),0.000001,Infinity))
  text(txt,4.5*length,(-yq+shadowy+yq+shadowy)/2);
 }
 }
 } else {
 if (nl == true) {
 translate(4.5*length,0)
 rotate(radians(180))
 translate(-4.5*length,-0)
 }
 if (txt != undefined && style != 'pointy') {
    textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  textSize(constrain(Math.min((abs(length)*100)/textWidth(txt)*0.95,abs(ys*abs(length)/1.5)),0.000001,Infinity))
  text(txt,4.5*length,0);
 }
 if (txt != undefined && style == 'pointy') {
    textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  textSize(constrain(Math.min(abs(length)*75/textWidth(txt)*(Math.min(abs(9*length)-rxs*abs(length)+0.01,constrain(rxs*abs(length),(6*abs(length))-rxs*abs(length)+0.01,rxs*abs(length)))*0.5/(abs(length)*2))*0.95,abs(ys*abs(length)/1.5)*0.80),0.000001,Infinity))
  text(txt,4.5*length,0);
 }
 }
 }
  pop();
}

function draw() {
  var wwidth = 710;
  var wheight = 522;
  background(255);
  fill('#ffd480');
  ellipse(wwidth/2,wheight/2,100)
  fill(0);
  var angle = 0;
  var x = 0;
  var y = 0;
  for (var a = 0; a < 360; a+=6) {
    angle = radians(a);
    x = wwidth/2 + cos(angle) * 48;
    y = wheight/2 + sin(angle) * 48;
    line(x,y,wwidth/2,wheight/2)
  }
  fill('#ffd480')
  noStroke();
  ellipse(wwidth/2,wheight/2,85)
  stroke(0);
  fill(0);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  angle = radians(90);
  x = wwidth/2 + cos(angle) * 35;
  y = wheight/2 + sin(angle) * 35;
  text('S',x,y)
  angle = radians(180);
  x = wwidth/2 + cos(angle) * 35;
  y = wheight/2 + sin(angle) * 35;
  text('W',x,y)
  angle = radians(270);
  x = wwidth/2 + cos(angle) * 35;
  y = wheight/2 + sin(angle) * 35;
  text('N',x,y)
  angle = radians(360);
  x = wwidth/2 + cos(angle) * 35;
  y = wheight/2 + sin(angle) * 35;
  text('E',x,y)
  for(var i=0; i<2; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<2; j++){
      fill(IncrClrVal(100,0.5,0,1,(i+j)*10), 100, 50);
      arrow(30+20*i,30+20*j,mouseX,mouseY,sin(frameCount/100)*2,5,3,'',undefined);
      fill(IncrClrVal(100,0.5,0,1,(i+2+j)*10), 100, 50);
      arrow(70+20*i,30+20*j,mouseX,mouseY,sin(frameCount/100)*2,5,3,undefined,'indication');
      fill(IncrClrVal(100,0.5,0,1,(i+j+2)*10), 100, 50);
      arrow(30+20*i,70+20*j,mouseX,mouseY,sin(frameCount/100)*2,5,3,undefined,'large');
      fill(IncrClrVal(100,0.5,0,1,(i+2+j+2)*10), 100, 50);
      arrow(70+20*i,70+20*j,mouseX,mouseY,sin(frameCount/100)*2,5,3,undefined,'pointy');
      fill(IncrClrVal(100,0.5,0,1,(i+4+j)*10), 100, 50);
      arrow(110+20*i,30+20*j,mouseX,mouseY,sin(frameCount/100)*2,5,3,'rotate',undefined,'3D',3,1);
      fill(IncrClrVal(100,0.5,0,1,(i+6+j)*10), 100, 50);
      arrow(150+20*i,30+20*j,mouseX,mouseY,sin(frameCount/100)*2,5,3,undefined,'indication','3D',3,1,'Hey!');
      fill(IncrClrVal(100,0.5,0,1,(i+4+j+2)*10), 100, 50);
      arrow(110+20*i,70+20*j,mouseX,mouseY,sin(frameCount/100)*2,5,3,undefined,'large','3D',3,1);
      fill(IncrClrVal(100,0.5,0,1,(i+6+j+2)*10), 100, 50);
      arrow(150+20*i,70+20*j,mouseX,mouseY,sin(frameCount/100)*2,5,3,undefined,'pointy','3D',3,1);
    }
  }
 push();
 var jitter = 0;
  if (Math.round(second()) % 2 === 0 && IncrClrVal(10,-0.1)-1.5 > 0 && IncrClrVal(10,0.1)-1.5 > 0) {
    jitter = random(-0.2, 0.2);
  } else {
  if (Math.round(Date.now()/7500)%2 === 0 && IncrClrVal(10,-0.1)-1.5 != IncrClrVal(10,0.1)-1.5) {
  jitter = IncrClrVal(10,-0.1)-1.5;
  } else if (Math.round(second()) % 2 != 0) {
  jitter = IncrClrVal(10,0.1)-1.5;
  }
 }
  x = cos(jitter) * wwidth;
  y = sin(jitter) * wheight;
  fill(5,100,50);
  arrow(wwidth/2, wheight/2, x, y,-5,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,'SOUTH')
  fill(60,100,50);
  arrow(wwidth/2, wheight/2, x, y,5,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,'NORTH')
 pop();
  fill(0);
 translate(-pmouseX+wwidth/2,-pmouseY+wheight/2)
  arrow(pmouseX, pmouseY, mouseX, mouseY,3,5,3/2);
 translate(pmouseX-wwidth/2,pmouseY-wheight/2)
  fill(80);
  arrow(wwidth/2, wheight/2, mouseX, mouseY,3,5,3/2);
 fill(50);
 ellipse(wwidth/2,wheight/2,8)
 var styles = ['normal','large','pointy','indication'];
  fill(IncrClrVal(100,0.5), 100, 50);
  arrow(270, 50,undefined,undefined,10)
  arrow(370, 50,undefined,undefined,10,undefined,undefined,undefined,'indication')
  arrow(470, 50,undefined,undefined,10,undefined,undefined,undefined,'large')
  arrow(570, 50,undefined,undefined,10,undefined,undefined,undefined,'pointy')
  arrow(270, 120,undefined,undefined,10,undefined,undefined,'rotate')
  arrow(370, 120,undefined,undefined,10,undefined,undefined,'rotate','indication')
  arrow(470, 120,undefined,undefined,10,undefined,undefined,'rotate','large')
  arrow(570, 120,undefined,undefined,10,undefined,undefined,'rotate','pointy')
 var xperspectiv = constrain(map(mouseX,30,240,0,2),0,2);
 var yperspectiv = constrain(map(mouseY,120,250,0,1),0,1);
  arrow(30, 150,undefined,undefined,10,undefined,undefined,undefined,styles[Math.floor(IncrClrVal(4,0.0005,0,0,0))],'3D',-xperspectiv,-yperspectiv)
  arrow(150, 150,undefined,undefined,10,undefined,undefined,undefined,styles[Math.floor(IncrClrVal(4,0.0005,0,0,1))],'3D',xperspectiv,-yperspectiv)
  arrow(30, 220,undefined,undefined,10,undefined,undefined,undefined,styles[Math.floor(IncrClrVal(4,0.0005,0,0,2))],'3D',-xperspectiv,yperspectiv)
  arrow(150, 220,undefined,undefined,10,undefined,undefined,undefined,styles[Math.floor(IncrClrVal(4,0.0005,0,0,3))],'3D',xperspectiv,yperspectiv)
  arrow(30, 300,undefined,undefined,10,undefined,undefined,'rotate',styles[Math.floor(IncrClrVal(4,0.0005,0,0,0))],'3D',-xperspectiv,-yperspectiv)
  arrow(150, 300,undefined,undefined,10,undefined,undefined,'rotate',styles[Math.floor(IncrClrVal(4,0.0005,0,0,1))],'3D',xperspectiv,-yperspectiv)
  arrow(30, 370,undefined,undefined,10,undefined,undefined,'rotate',styles[Math.floor(IncrClrVal(4,0.0005,0,0,2))],'3D',-xperspectiv,yperspectiv)
  arrow(150, 370,undefined,undefined,10,undefined,undefined,'rotate',styles[Math.floor(IncrClrVal(4,0.0005,0,0,3))],'3D',xperspectiv,yperspectiv)
 arrow(470,190,undefined,undefined,10,undefined,undefined,'rotate',styles[Math.floor(IncrClrVal(4,0.0005))],undefined,undefined,undefined,'SOME TEXT')
 arrow(570,190,undefined,undefined,10,undefined,undefined,'rotate',styles[Math.floor(IncrClrVal(4,0.0005))],'3d',1,1,'SOME TEXT')
 arrow(470+10*9,260,undefined,undefined,-10,undefined,undefined,'rotate',styles[Math.floor(IncrClrVal(4,0.0005))],'2d',undefined,undefined,'REVERSED')
 arrow(570+10*9,260,undefined,undefined,-10,undefined,undefined,'rotate',styles[Math.floor(IncrClrVal(4,0.0005))],'3d',1,1,'REVERSED')
 if (mouseX < 660 && mouseX > 570 && mouseY < 360 && mouseY > 300) {
  var xs1 = (mouseX-570)/10;
  var ys1 = (mouseY-330)/10;
 }
 arrow(570,330,undefined,undefined,10,xs1,ys1,undefined,styles[Math.floor(IncrClrVal(4,0.005))],'3d',1,1,'RESIZE ME!')
 if (mouseX < 560 && mouseX > 470 && mouseY < 360 && mouseY > 300) {
  var xs2 = (mouseX-470)/10;
  var ys2 = (mouseY-330)/10;
 }
 arrow(470,330,undefined,undefined,10,xs2,ys2,undefined,styles[Math.floor(IncrClrVal(4,0.005))],'2d',undefined,undefined,'RESIZE ME!')
 if (mouseX < 660 && mouseX > 570 && mouseY < 430 && mouseY > 370) {
  var xs3 = (wwidth-mouseX-(wwidth-660))/10;
  var ys3 = (wheight-mouseY-(wheight-400))/10;
 }
 arrow(570+90,400,undefined,undefined,-10,xs3,ys3,undefined,styles[Math.floor(IncrClrVal(4,0.005))],'3d',1,1,'RESIZE ME!')
 if (mouseX < 560 && mouseX > 470 && mouseY < 430 && mouseY > 370) {
  var xs4 = (wwidth-mouseX-(wwidth-560))/10;
  var ys4 = (wheight-mouseY-(wheight-400))/10;
 }
 arrow(470+90,400,undefined,undefined,-10,xs4,ys4,undefined,styles[Math.floor(IncrClrVal(4,0.005))],'2d',undefined,undefined,'RESIZE ME!')
 if (mouseX > 570 && mouseX < 660 && mouseY > 440 && mouseY < 500) {
 arrow(615-(constrain(mouseX,570,660)-570-90/2),470,mouseX,undefined,(constrain(mouseX,570,660)-570-90/2)/4.5,undefined,undefined,undefined,styles[Math.floor(IncrClrVal(4,0.005))],'3d',1,1,'REVERSE ME!')
 } else if (mouseX < 615) {
 arrow(660,470,mouseX,undefined,-10,undefined,undefined,undefined,styles[Math.floor(IncrClrVal(4,0.005))],'3d',1,1,'REVERSE ME!')
 } else {
 arrow(570,470,mouseX,undefined,10,undefined,undefined,undefined,styles[Math.floor(IncrClrVal(4,0.005))],'3d',1,1,'REVERSE ME!')
 }
 if (mouseX > 470 && mouseX < 560 && mouseY > 440 && mouseY < 500) {
 arrow(515-(constrain(mouseX,470,560)-470-90/2),470,undefined,undefined,(constrain(mouseX,470,560)-470-90/2)/4.5,undefined,undefined,undefined,styles[Math.floor(IncrClrVal(4,0.005))],'2d',undefined,undefined,'REVERSE ME!')
 } else if (mouseX < 515) {
 arrow(560,470,undefined,undefined,-10,undefined,undefined,undefined,styles[Math.floor(IncrClrVal(4,0.005))],'2d',undefined,undefined,'REVERSE ME!')
 } else {
 arrow(470,470,undefined,undefined,10,undefined,undefined,undefined,styles[Math.floor(IncrClrVal(4,0.005))],'2d',undefined,undefined,'REVERSE ME!')
 }
 if (mouseX > 160 && mouseX < 560 && mouseY > 275 && mouseY < 595) {
 arrow(310,400,undefined,undefined,10,undefined,undefined,undefined,styles[Math.floor(IncrClrVal(4,0.005,0,0,2))],'3d',(wwidth-355-constrain(mouseX,305,405))/5,(-wheight-constrain(mouseY+35,405,465)+435+wheight)/5,'HOVER ME!')
 } else {
 arrow(310,400,undefined,undefined,10,undefined,undefined,undefined,styles[Math.floor(IncrClrVal(4,0.005,0,0,2))],'2d',undefined,undefined,'HOVER ME!')
 }
 var demo = ['H','Hi','Hi ','Hi t','Hi th','Hi the','Hi ther','Hi there','Hi there!','Hi there!','Hi there!','Hi there!','Hi there!','W','We','Wel','Welc','Welco','Welcom','Welcome','Welcome ','Welcome t','Welcome to','Welcome to ','Welcome to t','Welcome to th','Welcome to the','Welcome to the ','Welcome to the a','Welcome to the ar','Welcome to the arr','Welcome to the arro','Welcome to the arrow','Welcome to the arrow ','Welcome to the arrow p','Welcome to the arrow pa','Welcome to the arrow par','Welcome to the arrow part','Welcome to the arrow party','Welcome to the arrow party!','Welcome to the arrow party!','Welcome to the arrow party!','Welcome to the arrow party!','Welcome to the arrow party!','Y','Yo','You','You ','You c','You ca','You can','You can ','You can t','You can ti','You can tic','You can tick','You can tickl','You can tickle','a','an','any','any ','any o','any of','any of ','any of m','any of my','any of my ','any of my f','any of my fr','any of my fri','any of my frie','any of my frien','any of my friend','any of my friends','a','an','and','and ','and s','and se','and see','and see ','and see i','and see if','and see if ','and see if t','and see if th','and see if the','and see if they','and see if they ','and see if they r','and see if they re','and see if they res','and see if they resp','and see if they respo','and see if they respon','and see if they respond','and see if they respond!','and see if they respond!','and see if they respond!','and see if they respond!','and see if they respond!','A','Al','Als','Also','Also ','Also I','Also I ','Also I c','Also I ca','Also I can','Also I can ','Also I can m','Also I can ma','Also I can mak','Also I can make','Also I can make ','Also I can make v','Also I can make ve','Also I can make ver','Also I can make very','Also I can make very ','Also I can make very v','Also I can make very ve','Also I can make very ver','Also I can make very very','Also I can make very very ','Also I can make very very v','Also I can make very very ve','Also I can make very very ver','Also I can make very very very','Also I can make very very very ','Also I can make very very very v','Also I can make very very very ve','Also I can make very very very ver','Also I can make very very very very','Also I can make very very very very ','Also I can make very very very very v','Also I can make very very very very ve','Also I can make very very very very ver','Also I can make very very very very very','Also I can make very very very very very ','Also I can make very very very very very v','Also I can make very very very very very ve','Also I can make very very very very very ver','Also I can make very very very very very very','Also I can make very very very very very very ','Also I can make very very very very very very l','Also I can make very very very very very very lo','Also I can make very very very very very very lon','Also I can make very very very very very very long','Also I can make very very very very very very long ','Also I can make very very very very very very long s','Also I can make very very very very very very long se','Also I can make very very very very very very long sen','Also I can make very very very very very very long sent','Also I can make very very very very very very long sente','Also I can make very very very very very very long senten','Also I can make very very very very very very long sentenc','Also I can make very very very very very very long sentence','Also I can make very very very very very very long sentences','Also I can make very very very very very very long sentences!','Also I can make very very very very very very long sentences!','Also I can make very very very very very very long sentences!','Also I can make very very very very very very long sentences!','Also I can make very very very very very very long sentences!']
 x = 142.5+cos(radians(IncrClrVal(360,2))) * 100;
  y = 460+sin(radians(IncrClrVal(360,2))) * 100;
  arrow(75, 460,undefined,undefined,15,undefined,undefined,undefined,styles[Math.floor(IncrClrVal(4,1/1670,0,0,0))],'3D',(wwidth-(wwidth-142.5)-x)/60,(wheight-(wheight-460)-y)/60,demo[Math.floor(IncrClrVal(167,0.1))])
 fill(0,100,50)
 arrow(135,240,135,340,5,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,'ROTATING')
 if (mouseX > 305 && mouseX < 405 && mouseY > 370 && mouseY < 430) {
 noCursor();
 push();
 translate(mouseX,mouseY)
 fill(0)
 stroke(85)
 fill(85)
 strokeWeight(1.5);
 rotate(radians(-10)+atan2(mouseY-400, mouseX-355))
 arrow(-18, -4, 0, 0,2,3,2.5);
 rotate(radians(10))
 stroke(100)
 fill(0)
 strokeWeight(1);
 arrow(-17, 0, 0, 0,2,3,2.5);
 pop();
 } else if (mouseX > 20 && mouseY > 20) {
 noCursor();
 push();
 strokeWeight(1.5);
 translate(mouseX,mouseY)
 rotate(radians(248))
  if (dist(mouseX, mouseY, wwidth/2, wheight/2) < 50) {
 stroke(85)
 fill(85)
 strokeWeight(1.5);
 rotate(radians(-10))
 arrow(-18, -4, 0, 0,2,3,2.5,'');
 rotate(radians(10))
 stroke(100)
 fill(0)
 strokeWeight(1);
 arrow(-17, 0, 0, 0,2,3,2.5,'');
 } else {
 stroke(85)
 fill(85)
 strokeWeight(1.5);
 rotate(radians(-10))
 arrow(-18, -4, 0, 0,2,3,2.5);
 rotate(radians(10))
 stroke(100)
 fill(0)
 strokeWeight(1);
 arrow(-17, 0, 0, 0,2,3,2.5);
 }
 rotate(radians(-248))
 pop();
 } else {
 cursor(ARROW);
 }
}



// Don't pay attention to these
function getDec(value) {
  return value % 1 ? value.toString().split(".")[1].length : 0;
}

function IncrClrVal(max,speed,dclg,sens,startdclg) {
  if (max == undefined) {
  max = 100; // 100 = max de données avant de reprendre à 0
  }
  if (speed == undefined || 0) {
  speed = 1; // 1 = 1 par seconde, si speed = undefined alors speed = le slideur 'rbaspeed' 
  }
  if (dclg == undefined) {
  dclg = 0; // décale toutes les valeurs en affectant le maximum ateint
  }
  if (sens == undefined || sens == '0') {
  sens = 1; // -1 --> augmente 1 --> diminu
  }
  if (startdclg == undefined || 0) {
  startdclg = 0; // décalage de départ, décale toutes les valeurs sans affecter le maximum ateint
  }
  return ((Math.sign(sens)*Math.round(Date.now()/(1000/60))*speed+startdclg) - max*Math.floor((Math.sign(sens)*Math.round(Date.now()/(1000/60))*speed+startdclg)/max)+dclg).toFixed(Math.max(getDec(startdclg),getDec(speed),getDec(max),getDec(dclg)));
}


function windowResized() {
    resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/p5.min.js"></script>
```